# How to make a gradle android app compatible with above api version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an app that works fine on API 19. However, I want it to work well in other API's as well. I'm targeting API 10 and above.

My gradle build looks like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}
```

But when I run the app on API 10 the AVD manager says `compatible: no`

How should I change my build so that it is compatible for API 10 and above?

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle config looks correct. Be sure to check your virtual device settings and compare to what you have defined in your manifest file. Also be sure to check any other modules you may have added to the project and their respective gradle and manifest files.

Comment: There isn't anything in my manifest files that would dictate the compatible version. ...I just have this line in there `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />`

Comment: If you are targeting API 10 and up. Try setting your minSdkVersion to 10 and targetSdkVersion to 18. You might also try rebooting AS and then going to Build->Clean Project then Build->Rebuild Project and then try running the project again. Gradle is sometimes finicky about syncing.

Comment: @birdy Did you ever get your app to build for API 10? If so how did you fix your issue?